# replacing text with a conditional pattern

Tags: r

I am importing a file with column names that take the following format:

```
x <- "text.text.text.text.name"
```

In most cases, the following line is good for removing everything before the final period, leaving only the variable name I want (`name`):

```
gsub(".*\\.","", x)
```

However, some variables have the following format:

```
y <- "text.text.text.text.name.R1"
```

I'd like to keep `name.R1` when the final period is followed by a capital "R". How would I modify the `gsub` argument to permit this change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@kasterma's solution worked best for me:

```
gsub("(.*\\.)([^R])","\\2", x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative look ahead to constrain the final period:

```
gsub(".*\\.(?!R)", "", x, perl = T)
# [1] "name"

gsub(".*\\.(?!R)", "", y, perl = T)
# [1] "name.R1"
```

Comment: Just to offer another solution: without having to go with perl regexps I have `gsub("(.*\\.)([^R])","\\2", x)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
gsub('.*\\.(\\w+.\\w+$)','\\1',y)
#[1] "name.R1"
```